# Java get list date between 2 dates

Tags: java, date, java-time

I'm working on Java Date(Java 8).
I have 2 dates, like: `2023-02-22` and `2023-02-28`

My expect output contains:

`2023-02-22`, `2023-02-23`, `2023-02-24`, `2023-02-25`, `2023-02-26`, `2023-02-27`, `2023-02-28`
Date format: `yyyy-MM-dd`

My code:

```
public List<String> getDatesBetween(@NotEmpty String fromDate, @NotEmpty String toDate) throws Exception {
     List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
     // get dates between 2 dates
     
     return dates;
}
```

How can I get list date from this date?
Thanks,

Comment: Please include your attempt at solving this problem and what issues you faced.

Comment: It can be usefull - [https://www.baeldung.com/java-between-dates https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-to-date]

Comment: Did you remember to search before asking? Asking because I’d be surprised if you didn’t find anything relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Java9+

You can use [`LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-) which is introduced from Java9:

> `public Stream<LocalDate> datesUntil​(LocalDate endExclusive)` 
> Returns a **sequential ordered stream of dates**. The returned stream starts from
> this date (inclusive) and goes to endExclusive (exclusive) by an
> incremental step of 1 day. 
> This method is equivalent to
> `datesUntil(endExclusive, Period.ofDays(1))`.

```
public List<String> getDatesBetween(@NotEmpty String fromDate, @NotEmpty String toDate){
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(fromDate);
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(toDate);
    return startDate.datesUntil(endDate.plusDays(1))
            .map(LocalDate::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

### Java8

I notice that you edit your question to ask for a solution using Java8, in this case, you can use:

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(fromDate);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(toDate);
return Stream.iterate(startDate, d -> d.plusDays(1))
        .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate.plusDays(1)))
        .map(LocalDate::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, use `LocalDate` for handling dates. Whenever you deal with dates/times, you should strongly consider using `java.time` over `String`s. You can convert `String`s to `LocalDate`s using `LocalDate.parse`:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(fromDate, formatter);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(toDate, formatter);
```

Then, you can just add one day over and over until you reach the same date:

```java
for(LocalDate date = startDate; !endDate.isBefore(date); date = date.plusDays(1)){
    dates.add(date.format(formatter));
    //dates.add(date);//if you want to work with a List<LocalDate>
}
```

Summing up, you can use it in your method like this:

```java
public List<String> getDatesBetween(@NotEmpty String fromDate, @NotEmpty String toDate) throws Exception {
    List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(fromDate, formatter);
    LocalDate endDate =  LocalDate.parse(toDate, formatter);
    for(LocalDate date = startDate; !endDate.isBefore(date); date = date.plusDays(1)){   
      dates.add(date.format(formatter));
    }
    return dates;
}
```

As, [shmosel mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75589148/java-get-list-date-between-2-dates/75589219?noredirect=1#comment133359099_75589219), `LocalDate` uses the [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE) by default so you don't have to provide a `DateTimeFormatter` in your case:

```java
public List<String> getDatesBetween(@NotEmpty String fromDate, @NotEmpty String toDate) throws Exception {
    List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(fromDate);
    LocalDate endDate =  LocalDate.parse(toDate);
    for(LocalDate date = startDate; !endDate.isBefore(date); date = date.plusDays(1)){
        dates.add(date.toString());
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the formatter. `yyyy-MM-dd` is the default.

Comment: … and it should have been a `DateTimeFormatter`, not a `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have integrated that in my answer. (such things happen when writing code directly in the answer box)